# How to manage tristate in flutter checkbox if the nullsafety is enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

Does any one have an idea how to manage checkbox in flutter in null safety mode?
Theres three states false, true and null. Since variables cant be null now how to actually use it with null safety. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The tristate field allows you to define whether the value field can be null.

If you set the tristate to true then you can just use a nullable boolean as the input!

```
bool? value = null;
```

Then

```
Checkbox(value: value, tristate: true, ...)
```